# Create column that's average of previous 10 obs of different column

Tags: r, time-series

I have some time series data on stocks. Say hourly data, 1 to 100, and the volume of that stock being traded for each hour. I'm trying to create a third, binary variable to indicate abnormal volume - defined as an hour with volume 10% larger than the average of the 24 preceding hours.

```
stocks.df <- cbind(c(1:100), volume.vector)
```

I'm sure this can be done with some gnarly loops, but I bet there's a better solution with dplyr (always is).

```
if (stocks.df[i,volume] > mean(stocks.df[i-10:i,volume) unusualvol <- 1 else unusualvol <- 0
```

This is my best guess without including the 10% cutoff. Perhaps this is better done in the xts package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `rollapply()` from the package `zoo` like this:

```r
library(xts)
set.seed(42)
volume <- rlnorm(100) * 1000
ts <- xts(volume, order.by = Sys.Date() - 100:1)
tail(ts)
#>                 [,1]
#> 2018-01-05  329.2991
#> 2018-01-06  422.8268
#> 2018-01-07  322.4721
#> 2018-01-08  232.4189
#> 2018-01-09 1083.2682
#> 2018-01-10 1921.6887
tail(ts > 1.1 * lag(rollapply(ts, 10, mean), k = 1)
#>             [,1]
#> 2018-01-05 FALSE
#> 2018-01-06 FALSE
#> 2018-01-07 FALSE
#> 2018-01-08 FALSE
#> 2018-01-09 FALSE
#> 2018-01-10  TRUE
```

The call to `lag()` makes sure that you compare the current volume with the average of the *previous* ten data points.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I found some other suggestions using rollapply, but the use of lists to achieve the lag is confusing: mavrg <- rollapplyr(x[,1],list(-(3:1)),mean,fill=NA)